# How to authenticate IMAP using gmail OAuth?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, imap

I am building a java micro-service to read mails.

I am trying to connect to com.sun.mail:javax-mail:1.5.5 imap using google's OAuth token, I am sending access_token in place of password and its throwing Authentication error.

[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.imaps.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");

 Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, "testingqa1919@gmail.com", accessToken);
```

Comment: Did you try with`Store store = session.getStore("imap");`? And enable the IMAP in your gmail? Also, did you enable the less secure apps in your gmail?

Comment: Can you turn on the protocol trace to see what is being sent?

Comment: @HasithaMJayawardana I have enabled both imap and less secured app as I can login using my credentials. I have tried [link](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2) from here

Comment: @Max I don't know how, but I will find out and do that. Thank you.

Comment: How are you getting the token? Make sure you're using an access token, and not a refresh token. Note that you **don't** need to enable less secure apps to use OAuth. Also, IMAP being enabled/disabled in the Gmail settings doesn't affect OAuth clients (only the G Suite admin setting for IMAP on/off affects OAuth IMAP apps, and of course if the user revokes access to the app).

Comment: @Liron its working now. There was error in parsing access token.

Comment: Thanks @TRB! I added this as an answer, to help people who hit this problem in the future. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using an access token, and not a refresh token.